# Cannot Use PySide on WIndows

Tags: python, pyside, canopy

I am trying to use the pyside tool on Windows to make a python file out of a .ui
I've installed pyside version 1.2.1-6 from the canopy distribution.

```
C:\Users\nick\Desktop\pump_project>pyside-uic.exe history_dialog.ui -o kalimera.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\nick\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\scripts\pyside-uic-scr
ipt.py", line 8, in <module>
from PySide.scripts.uic import main
ImportError: No module named scripts.uic
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an error in your .ui?

pyside-uic apparently works fine for me, at least doesn't fail (using Canopy 1.4.1) compiling this example .ui -- [https://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside-examples/source/d4e4c7fdf71ab52083e49ffdea1b7daeff6c8d8d:examples/pyuic/demo.ui](https://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside-examples/source/d4e4c7fdf71ab52083e49ffdea1b7daeff6c8d8d%3aexamples/pyuic/demo.ui)